# Feed listview with Firebase Database using custom Adapters and Rows

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know similar questions have been asked here before, but none of them seem to help me, so here I am, trying to retrieve the data from my firebase database: [image: firebase database] in `ShiftInformation/1515547726961/PatientInformatin/5512552` and cast it to my listview in **PatientActivity**.

```
public class PatientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ListView listview;
private List<Patient> patientList;
DatabaseReference dref;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    getPatientList();
    ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(PatientActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,patientList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public List<Patient> getPatientList(){
    patientList = new ArrayList<>();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference shiftRef = rootRef.child("UserInformation").child("Shift").child(user.getUid()).child("Shift");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String ushift = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                DatabaseReference PatientInfo = rootRef.child("ShiftInformation/" + ushift + "/PatientInformation");

                final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(PatientActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, patientList);
                PatientInfo.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                       Patient patient = dataSnapshot.getValue(Patient.class);
                        String txtTitle = patient.getPatientName();
                        String txtLeito = patient.getPatientLeito();
                        list.add(new Patient(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, txtTitle, txtLeito));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        list.remove(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    shiftRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    return patientList;
}
```

My **ListViewAdapter.java** looks like this:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Patient> {

public ListViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Patient> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;

    if (v==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    Patient patient = getItem(position);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView txtLeito = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtLeito);

    //img.setImageResource(patient.getImageId());
    txtTitle.setText(patient.getPatientName());
    txtLeito.setText(patient.getPatientLeito());

    return v;

}
```

and my **Patient.java** looks like this:
public class Patient {

```
private int imageId;
private String patientName;
private String patientLeito;

public Patient(int imageId, String patientName, String patientLeito){
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.patientName = patientName;
    this.patientLeito = "Leito "+patientLeito;
}

/*    public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}

public void setImageId(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}*/

public String getPatientName() {
    return patientName;
}

public void setPatientName(String patientName) {
    this.patientName = patientName;
}

public String getPatientLeito() {
    return patientLeito;
}

public void setPatientLeito(String patientLeito) {
    this.patientLeito = patientLeito;
}
```

**Question**
I have been getting the following error when compiling the app. Since my Patient can only return those strings, I cannot think of how to fix this!
[image: error]

Comment: You have declared your patientLeito as String, but it is stored as int in your database

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!! The issue is that i don't even get to run the app, regardless of the database. The data in the picture is just something I made up in order to give an example of what it should look like when the app is used propperly.

Comment: That's because you're adding your Patient object to your String list. Maybe you wanted to do `patientList.add(new Patient(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, txtTitle, txtLeito));` ?